# Activity Manifest file error For Android Apllication

Tags: android

I'm trying to add an activity. I am trying to create an Application

```
<activity android:name=".About"
          android:label="@string/about_title"
          android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">            
</activity>
```

I did this, but when I ran my application my emulator gives me error message. The message is "Sorry the application Sudoku (process org.example.Sudoku ) has stopped unexpectedly. please try again".Error showing in log cat

```
08-02 07:25:51.093: D/AndroidRuntime(270): Shutting down VM
08-02 07:25:51.093: W/dalvikvm(270): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception  
(group=0x4001d800)
08-02 07:25:51.153: E/AndroidRuntime(270): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-02 07:25:51.153: E/AndroidRuntime(270): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start 
activity ComponentInfo{org.example.sudoku/org.example.sudoku.Sudoku}:   
java.lang.NullPointerException
08-02 07:25:51.153: E/AndroidRuntime(270):  at 
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
08-02 07:25:51.153: E/AndroidRuntime(270):  at    
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
08-02 07:25:51.153: E/AndroidRuntime(270):  at  
android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
08-02 07:25:51.153: E/AndroidRuntime(270):  at  
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
08-02 07:25:51.153: E/AndroidRuntime(270):  at 
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-02 07:25:51.153: E/AndroidRuntime(270):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
08-02 07:25:51.153: E/AndroidRuntime(270):  at 
android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
08-02 07:25:51.153: E/AndroidRuntime(270):  at 
java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-02 07:25:51.153: E/AndroidRuntime(270):  at   
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-02 07:25:51.153: E/AndroidRuntime(270):  at   
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-02 07:25:51.153: E/AndroidRuntime(270):  at  
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-02 07:25:51.153: E/AndroidRuntime(270):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native  
Method)
08-02 07:25:51.153: E/AndroidRuntime(270): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-02 07:25:51.153: E/AndroidRuntime(270):  at 
org.example.sudoku.Sudoku.onCreate(Sudoku.java:20)
08-02 07:25:51.153: E/AndroidRuntime(270):  at  
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
08-02 07:25:51.153: E/AndroidRuntime(270):  at 
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
08-02 07:25:51.153: E/AndroidRuntime(270):  ... 11 more
```

My sudoku.java file code:

```
public class Sudoku extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    View continueButton = findViewById(R.id.continue_button);
    continueButton.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
    View newButton = findViewById(R.id.new_button);
    newButton.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
    View aboutButton = findViewById(R.id.about_button);
    aboutButton.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
    View exitButton = findViewById(R.id.exit_button);
    exitButton.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.about_button:
    Intent i = new Intent(this, About.class);
    startActivity(i);
    break;

    }
}
```

here is the main.xml file.

```
    android:background="@color/background"
    android:padding="30dip"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center">

    <TextView
    android:text="@string/main_title"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_marginBottom="25dip"
    android:textSize="24.5sp" />

<Button

    android:id="@+id/continue_button"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/continue_label" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/new_game_button"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/new_game_label" />
<Button

    android:id="@+id/about_button"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/about_label" />
<Button

    android:id="@+id/exit_button"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/exit_label" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: In addition to that do you receive addition message in your [LogCat](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html)? Check those mesage and post them.

Comment: in your Sudoku.java file line 20 is throwing a NullPointerException, post the file so we can figure it out

Comment: Hey error showing in log cat
08-02 07:25:51.093: D/AndroidRuntime(270): Shutting down VM
08-02 07:25:51.093: W/dalvikvm(270): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
08-02 07:25:51.153: E/AndroidRuntime(270): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-02 07:25:51.153: E/AndroidRuntime(270): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{org.example.sudoku/org.example.sudoku.Sudoku}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-02 07:25:51.153: E/AndroidRuntime(270):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)

Comment: Post your `Sudoku` class. There ios some error in `onCreate` .

Comment: post your main.xml source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change new_button to new_game_button in your code
Since in XML it is written as new_game_button but in code you are using it as new_button

Answer (score 0):

Check your code at line 20, it's NullPointerException

```
08-02 07:25:51.153: E/AndroidRuntime(270): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException

08-02 07:25:51.153: E/AndroidRuntime(270): at org.example.sudoku.Sudoku.onCreate(Sudoku.java:20)
```

Comment: I am new in android. so if can brief on me that it would be great helpful. where exactly i should look.

Comment: Here i am giving my Sudoku class.

Comment: protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

  setContentView(R.layout.main);

  View continueButton = findViewById(R.id.continue_button);

  continueButton.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);

  View newButton = findViewById(R.id.new_button);

  newButton.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);

  View aboutButton = findViewById(R.id.about_button);

  aboutButton.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);

  View exitButton = findViewById(R.id.exit_button);

  exitButton.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
}

Comment: hey Yushulx i have added the sudoku class. i can not find any problem here. can you help me.

Comment: it is new_game_button not new_button. That's why you got null

Answer (score 0):

I think u have to type cast u r view

```
View continueButton = (View)findViewById(R.id.continue_button);
    continueButton.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
    View newButton = (View)findViewById(R.id.new_button);
    newButton.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
    View aboutButton = (View)findViewById(R.id.about_button);
    aboutButton.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
    View exitButton = (View)findViewById(R.id.exit_button);
    exitButton.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
```

Try dis i hope it will work for u

Or u have to do changes something like this

```
Button continueButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.continue_button);
        continueButton.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
        View newButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.new_button);
        newButton.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
        View aboutButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.about_button);
        aboutButton.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
        View exitButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.exit_button);
        exitButton.setOnClickListener((OnClickListener) this);
```